# Contents of Custom QTableWidget class gets shrinked to very small size

Tags: python, pyqt5, resize, qtableview, qtablewidget

I Created a class that derives the QTableWidget class in Pyqt5, after doing so I tired to display contents (Static content on loading and dynamic content afterward) , but the table size is not fitting the size of the parent frame. (PS : doing setFixedHeight/Width works but it wont resize on resizing the parent)

```
    def __init__(self,parent:QTableView):
        super(STable, self).__init__(parent)

    def init_table(self, row=1, cols=0, headers=None):
        if headers is None:
            headers = []
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setColumnCount(cols)
        self.setRowCount(row)
        self.setFixedWidth(self.parent().width())
        self.setFixedHeight(self.parent().height())
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
        print(self.parentWidget().geometry())
        print(self.parentWidget().objectName())
        # both print statement print the geometry as 0,0,100,30 and name as the correct parent's name
        # geometry is wrong as the parent frame is occupying 800x800
        # doesn't work
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to adapt the size of a widget to its parent, then use a layout on the parent. Otherwise, provide a MRE as requested by eyllanesc, but be aware that when you say "the parent frame is occupying 800x800" that's only valid **if** you explicitly set the parent size *before* adding the child, otherwise the widget has a standard size (normally 640x480 if not limited by maximumSize).